# Listview duplicates items with data from a CursorAdapter subclass

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have read various posts on listview duplicating items but none of them seemed to have a good solution to a listview that uses a CursorAdapter subclass.

Am trying to populate my listview with data from my database table using a class that **extends CursorAdapter**.

when i start the activity that has my listview **for the first time**. list items are not duplicated.

- Joseph
- Kim

**but** any subsequent call to this activity, the following is shown in my listview

- Kim
- Kim

I have read about using **ViewHolder** but i want a fresh copy of data in my listview from my database **every time i call this activity**

below is my list adapter implementation

```
 public class ChatAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater cursorInfrlater;
    View view;

    public ChatAdapter(Context context,Cursor cursor, int flags){
        super(context,cursor,flags);
        cursorInfrlater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view , Context context ,Cursor cursor){

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){

            TextView name =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sender_name);
            name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistory.COLUMN_NAME_SENDER_NAME)));
            TextView message =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            message.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistory.COLUMN_NAME_MESSAGE)));
            TextView unread =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            unread.setText(Integer.toString(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ChatHistory.COLUMN_NAME_UNREAD_MESSAGES))));

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,Cursor cursor, ViewGroup viewGroup){
        view = cursorInfrlater.inflate(R.layout.chat_row_layout,viewGroup,false);
        return view;
    }
}
```

**implementation of my activity**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.chat_displayer);

        final ChatMessages cmc = new ChatMessages();
        cmc.deleteNotifications(this);
        ChatAdapter chatAdapter = cmc.getChatHistory(this);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(chatAdapter);
```

**What should** i implement to remove this duplication of listitems?

Comment: just use `SimpleCursorAdapter`, no need for extending anything, you just create an adapter and call `setAdapter`, that's all

Comment: from the doc of `CursorAdapter.bindView(...)` *cursor-The cursor from which to get the data. **The cursor is already moved to the correct position.***

Comment: @Selvin  yah. i have learnt that from Blackbelt's answer below

Comment: @pskink  i dont think `SimpleCursorAdapter` can fulfill all my needs of **filling various views in my list item row with data**

Comment: **but i think so**, just try it and you will save a lot of time and possible bugs in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
 cursor.moveToFirst();
 while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
 cursor.moveToNext();
```

from `bindView`. The method is called at least `cursor.getCount()` times, so you don't need to loop around the cursor itself